# What is the proper way of inheritance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

why is it said that in ruby instance method gets inherited by the subclass instead of instance variable of the superclass ? 
from the code one can clearly see that @order which is a instance variable in 
ruby is inherited by the subclass method Price_demand

```
class Management

    def price
        @OrderNo=4
        @Order =4
        puts "the price of order #{@OrderNo.to_s} is $40"
    end
    def exe
        puts "print #{@Order.to_s}"
    end

    def rant
        puts "please hurry with the order"
    end 
end


class Waiter < Management


    def Price_demand
        puts "the price of #{@Order.to_s} is $5"
    end
end


a=Waiter.new
a.price 
a.exe
a.Price_demand
puts a.instance_variables
```

Comment: `...instead of instance variable of the superclass` - can you cite any documentation to support your statement?

Comment: it is there in a book 'Head First Ruby' at Page no 84

Answer (score 1):

The instance variables will not come into existence until they are initialized through assignment.  This is true whether the class is inherited or not.  For instance, for the parent class `Management`, following is observed

```
m = Management.new
p m.instance_variables
#=> []
m.price
p m.instance_variables
#=> [:@OrderNo, :@Order]
```

Relating that to inheritance seems confusing, and I would say author of "Head First Ruby" book has unnecessarily confused the readers in that section of the book.

---

If you had a constructor in `Management` class that initialized instance variables to user supplied or default values, then, you would see those instance variables listed in response of `instance_variables` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are no instance variables of the subclass or the superclass. Instance variables are properties of *instances*, not classes. That's why they are called "instance" variables, after all!

Once you understand that, your code should become clear: the instance variable belongs to `a`. It doesn't matter where the method that modifies it was defined.

[Note: Obviously, classes are instances, too (of class `Class`), so they can have instance variables of their own, but that is not what we are talking about here.]

Comment: I am a little confused regarding variable declaration in Ruby inside class cant we declare any variable inside class like class Management holla="hi" end

Comment: Yes, sure, class bodies can have local variables. Note that local variables don't belong to objects, they belong to lexical scopes.